# Kubernetes - access the terminal

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to open the terminal inside the container and execute the command.

When I use this: kubectl exec -it POD_NAME, I cannot connect, I see connection timeout.

Do you know other methods instead of kubectl exec to open a terminal inside the container?

Comment: you need to specify which command you want to run.. for exmaple `kubectl exec -it POD_NAME bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

ssh into the Kubernetes node/machine where your container is running and run:

```sh
$ docker exec -it <container-name> sh
```

or if you have bash in the container

```sh
$ docker exec -it <container-name> bash
```

The fact that it's timing out means that you may have some other networking issues in your cluster like a firewall preventing access, your kube-apiserver not being accessible, or your network overlay not configured the way it's supposed to.

[This is the best guide I know](https://erkanerol.github.io/post/how-kubectl-exec-works/) to understand how `kubectl exec ...` works under the hood, if you'd like to understand where things might be wrong.